# Design: an array of "enemy" objects for game AI

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I made shoot em up like game.But I have only one ememy which fallows me on screen.But I want to make  lots of enemys like each 10 second they will across on screen together 5 or 10 enemys.

```
 ArrayList<Enemies> enemy = new ArrayList<Enemies>();

 for (Enemies e : enemy) {

        e.draw(g);
    }
```

is it good creating array list and then showing on screen? 
And Do I have to make some planing movements thoose enemies in my code ? I want that they vill appear not on same pozition.Like First 5 enemies will come top of screen then the other 5 or 10 enemies will come from left side.. so on.What is best solution for this?

And I have problem where to fullfiel this array  like

```
enemy.add(new Enemies(750,60))
```

But this doesnt work  ((

Comment: almost +1 for the great title

Comment: @Thilo: yes, but I've changed it to be a bit more descriptive

Comment: New title is more useful/practical... but I liked the original one a lot better.  (Indeed, it was the main reason I clicked through in the first place.)

Comment: For the people who can't view the edit-history, the original title was "How to make enemies?" :D

Comment: I'd change the name of your class 'Enemies' to 'Enemy'.  'Enemies' is plural and implies a collection, when really you want a collection of singular enemies - 'Enemy'.  Therefore you array list may be 'List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>()'.  Its semantics, not a big deal in the long run, but it does make a difference in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example a random property and onScreen property. And set them when you show them on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create an ArrayList for enemies, it's a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize the starting position ofthe enemies using the Random class. At the point where you create the enemy select Random coordinates for each.

You may want to have each enemy run in its own thread so that they move independent of each other too.